# How to improve performance of channels for large number of tasks and fast workers

Tags: go

I want to efficiently solve a problem that is conceputally similar to finding the average pairwise distance of `P` points in space, which is the example I use for the sake of this question. The computation can be well parallelized and so I wanted to tackle it with Go. In a sequential program I would need to run two nested loops, the outer one over `i = 0...P-1` and the inner one over `j = i+1...P-1`. I would then calculate the distance between points `i` and `j`, sum them all up and in the end divide by the number of point pairs. The calculations therefore need to cover a "triangle" of the possible point pair combinations.

In Go my first attempt was to use the same logic, but to distribute the calculations to worker functions via channels. My approach looks at follows:

```
package main

import "math"
import "sync"
import "fmt"
import "math/rand"
import "github.com/schollz/progressbar"

const nProcs = 32
const nPoints = 30000

type Pair struct {
    p1 [3]float64
    p2 [3]float64
}

func square(f float64) (float64) {
    return f * f
}

func progress(total int64, ch <-chan int) {
    bar := progressbar.Default(total)
    for i := range ch {
        bar.Add(i)
    }
}

func worker(idx int, sumBuffer []float64, in <-chan Pair, out chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    count := int64(0)
    
    defer wg.Done();
    
    for pair := range in {
        dist := math.Sqrt(square(pair.p1[0]-pair.p2[0]) + square(pair.p1[1]-pair.p2[1]) + square(pair.p1[2]-pair.p2[2]))
        sumBuffer[idx] += dist
        
        count++
        if count % (2<<15) == 0 {
            out <- (2<<15)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    var sumBuffer [nProcs]float64
    var points    [nPoints][3]float64
    
    var sum float64
    
    for i := 0; i < nPoints; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 3; j++ {
            points[i][j] = rand.Float64()
        }
    }
    
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{};
    wg.Add(nProcs);
    
    progressCh := make(chan int, 4 * nProcs)
    pairCh := make(chan Pair, 4 * nProcs)
    nPairs := int64(nPoints - 1) * int64(nPoints) / int64(2)
    go progress(nPairs, progressCh)
    
    for i := 0; i < nProcs; i++ {
        go worker(i, sumBuffer[:], pairCh, progressCh, wg)
    }
    
    for i := int64(0); i < nPoints; i++ {
        for j := int64(i+1); j < nPoints; j++ {
            pairCh <- Pair{points[i], points[j]}
        }
    }
    
    close(pairCh)
    wg.Wait();
    
    for i := 0; i < nProcs; i++ {
        sum += sumBuffer[i]
    }
    sum /= float64(nPairs)
    
    fmt.Println("Average distance:", sum)
}
```

This program, however, did not run as fast as I would have expected. In a second try, I got rid of the channels to distribute the tasks and instead partitioned the calculations between the workers by hand. Then, every worker needs to calculate initially, which part of the "triangle" it has to cover, which is quite cumbersome.

```
package main

import "math"
import "sync"
import "fmt"
import "math/rand"
import "github.com/schollz/progressbar"

const nProcs = 32
const nPoints = 30000

func square(f float64) (float64) {
    return f * f
}

func progress(total int64, ch <-chan int) {
    bar := progressbar.Default(total)
    for i := range ch {
        bar.Add(i)
    }
}

func worker(idx int, points [][3]float64, sumBuffer []float64, start int64, stop int64, out chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    count := start
    length := int64(len(points))
    
    defer wg.Done();
    
    // Calculate start value for loop index i
    iStart := int64(0)
    pointCount := int64(0)
    for k := length - 1; k >= 0; k-- {
        if pointCount + k > start {
            break
        } else {
            pointCount += k
            iStart++
        }
    }
    firstLoop := true
        
    for i := int64(iStart); i < length && count < stop; i++ {
        // Calculate start value for loop index j
        var jStart int64
        if firstLoop {
            jStart = (i + 1) + (start - pointCount)
        } else {
            jStart = i + 1
        }
        
        for j := int64(jStart); j < length && count < stop; j++ {
            dist := math.Sqrt(square(points[i][0]-points[j][0]) + square(points[i][1]-points[j][1]) + square(points[i][2]-points[j][2]))
            sumBuffer[idx] += dist
            
            count++
            if count % (2<<15) == 0 {
                out <- (2<<15)
            }
        }
        
        firstLoop = false
    }
}

func main() {
    var sumBuffer [nProcs]float64
    var points    [nPoints][3]float64
    
    var sum float64
    
    for i := 0; i < nPoints; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 3; j++ {
            points[i][j] = rand.Float64()
        }
    }
    
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{};
    wg.Add(nProcs);
    
    progressCh := make(chan int, 4 * nProcs)
    nPairs := int64(nPoints - 1) * int64(nPoints) / int64(2)
    go progress(nPairs, progressCh)
    
    step := int64(math.Ceil(float64(nPairs) / float64(nProcs)))
    for i := 0; i < nProcs; i++ {
        go worker(i, points[:], sumBuffer[:], int64(i) * step, int64(i+1) * step, progressCh, wg)
    }

    wg.Wait();
    
    for i := 0; i < nProcs; i++ {
        sum += sumBuffer[i]
    }
    sum /= float64(nPairs)
    
    fmt.Println("Average distance:", sum)
}
```

Now the second program is about 100 times faster! However, I don't even use the advantages of Go in that version and I could have written the same program in C++. How can the first program be improved such that the overhead introduced by using channels is not so dramatic? Or is this just the limit of how efficient channels are and for my usecase channels are simply not the way to go?

Apart from that, I'm quite new to Go. I'm sure my program is not quite ideomatic for Go. Any comments on how to improve my style are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The channel version is probably slower because the work (calculating distance) is very small relative to the overhead of scheduling & communicating between the goroutines.

It's better to divide the point pairs into larger chunks, as you did in your second example.

Here's a simplistic approach to see what's going on:

```
var sum float64
var count int64

for i, p := range points {
    for _, p2 := range points[i+1:] {
        sum += p.distanceTo(p2)
        count++
    }
}

fmt.Printf("%d points, %d pairs, avg %f\n", len(points), count, sum/float64(count))
```

When I try this, my laptop gets hot, then outputs:

```
100000 points, 4999950000 pairs, avg 0.660843
duration 22.623835855s
```

Each distance calculation takes about 5 nanoseconds, that's extremely fast, and too small a division of work.

Only one cpu core is doing the work:

[image: single cpu]

Since my laptop has 8 cores, I tried to create an example with 8 workers working on equal chunks of the point pairs.

```
8 workers, 100000 points, 4999950000 pairs, avg 0.660843
duration 7.481476421s
```

It's not 8 x faster, but it's an improvement, and puts those idle cores to work:

[image]

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "math/rand"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

const nPoints = 100000

var points [nPoints]*Point

type Point struct {
    x, y, z float64
}

func (p *Point) distanceTo(p2 *Point) float64 {
    a := p.x - p2.x
    b := p.y - p2.y
    c := p.z - p2.z
    return math.Sqrt(a*a + b*b + c*c)
}

func main() {
    initPoints()

    start := time.Now()
    run()
    fmt.Printf("duration %v\n", time.Since(start))
}

func initPoints() {
    for i := 0; i < nPoints; i++ {
        points[i] = &Point{rand.Float64(), rand.Float64(), rand.Float64()}
    }
}

func run() {
    requests := make(chan Request)
    results := make(chan Result)

    nWorkers := runtime.NumCPU() //change, eg: 1 or 2

    for n := 0; n < nWorkers; n++ {
        go worker(requests, results)
    }

    go func() {
        nPairs := nPoints * (nPoints - 1) / 2
        batchSize := nPairs / nWorkers

        req := Request{iStart: 0, jStart: 1, count: 0}

        for i := 0; i < nPoints; i++ {
            for j := i + 1; j < nPoints; j++ {
                req.count++
                if req.count == batchSize {
                    requests <- req
                    req = Request{iStart: i, jStart: j, count: 0}
                }
            }
        }

        if req.count > 0 {
            requests <- req
        }

        close(requests)
    }()

    var sum, avg float64
    var count int64

    for n := 0; n < nWorkers; n++ {
        r := <-results
        fmt.Printf("worker %d: %v\n", n+1, r)
        sum += r.sum
        count += r.count
    }
    close(results)

    if count > 0 {
        avg = sum / float64(count)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%d workers, %d points, %d pairs, avg %f\n", nWorkers, len(points), count, avg)
}

func worker(requests chan Request, results chan Result) {
    r := Result{}
    for req := range requests {
        req.work(&r)
    }

    results <- r
}

func (req *Request) work(result *Result) {
    count := 0
    jStart := req.jStart

    for i := req.iStart; i < nPoints; i++ {
        p := points[i]

        if i > req.iStart {
            jStart = i + 1
        }

        for j := jStart; j < nPoints; j++ {
            p2 := points[j]

            result.sum += p.distanceTo(p2)
            result.count++

            count++
            if count == req.count {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}

type Request struct {
    iStart int
    jStart int
    count  int
}

type Result struct {
    sum   float64
    count int64
}

func (r Result) String() string {
    avg := 0.0
    if r.count > 0 {
        avg = r.sum / float64(r.count)
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d comparisons, avg distance %f", r.count, avg)
}
```

The [pprof profiling blog post](https://blog.golang.org/pprof) is a great demonstration of techniques to see where a program is spending it's time.